# What properties does the linear space of all convergent sequences in R with the sup norm hold? And why?

Tags: real-analysis

I am thinking that the space is complete, and maybe there are certain sets that are compact in the space, and X* is isomorphic to the space with the sup norm. 
But I totally got stuck with the proofs, any hints?

Comment: So, you're looking for proofs that the space is complete, and a characterisation of the dual space? I don't really understand what you want regarding compact sets; every normed linear space admits compact sets (e.g. singleton sets).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question itself is a bit ambiguous. I think I got the first part on proving it is complete, now I am wondering what sets are compact on the space of l-infinity(all bounded sequences in R) with the sup norm, and what properties does the dual of l-infinity hold.

Comment: In the title, you mention the space of convergent sequences in $\Bbb{R}$ under the sup norm; this space is sometimes denoted as $c$. But, you're talking about $\ell^\infty$, the space of all bounded sequences in $\Bbb{R}$? Which questions in your post pertain to $\ell^\infty$ and which pertain to the subspace $c$?

Comment: Aren't they the same thing? I though here convergent and boundedness can mean each other...

Comment: They aren't the same thing. Every convergent sequence is bounded, but not vice-versa. For example, the sequence $(-1)^n$ is bounded, since $|(-1)^n| \le 1$, but it's not convergent.